# delay in ACK packets for ldap abandon request

Tags: ldap, tcp

we have migrated from an openldap server on linux to a DirX on windows 2008. The ldap server und normal serch request behaves as expected. 
However with some applications (weblogic deployed webapps) are expreriening performance problems.

We traced the network activity and found that when the client sends an 'abandon' operation the ldap server sends and ACK with a RTT of aournd 0.1 - 0.2s.

We're not 100% sure but we think that this is where the performance hit comes from. the interaction we looked at had 270 abandons and 179 of the ACKS had an RTT of > 0.2s.

Not being that familiar with the TCP i've got the following questions:

1. an ACK sent in response to the receipt of a packet is independent of how long the recipient will take to process what ever data was sent. this happens at the tcp level before the recipient has even received the incoming payload (in our case abandon). right?
2. all other interactions say searchrequest/searchresponse have the ack in the payload packet. this is 'delayed ack'? they only take about 0.01 s and thats includeing payload and presumably computation. So why are individual ACKS sent for the abandons? or to put the question like this: when are individual acks sent as opposed to combined ack+data?

   ```
   657 9.2943  ldapserver  ldapclient  LDAP    170 searchResDone(57)                                                          
   658 9.2948  ldapclient  ldapserver  TCP 66  18367 > 389 [ACK] Seq=10007 Ack=19799 Len=0  
   659 9.2954  ldapclient  ldapserver  LDAP    1009    searchRequest(134)                                         
   660 9.2972  ldapserver  ldapclient  LDAP    630 searchResEntry(134)                                        
   661 9.2973  ldapserver  ldapclient  LDAP    172 searchResDone(134)                                             
                                                           Sequence number:45106, len=106
   662 9.2978  ldapclient  ldapserver  LDAP    76  abandonRequest(134)                                                            
                                                           Sequence number: 46818, len=10


   663 9.3378  ldapclient  ldapserver  TCP 66  18368 > 389 [ACK] Seq=46828 Ack=45212 Len=0            
                                                           (The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.040492000 seconds)
   664 9.5062  ldapserver  ldapclient  TCP 66  389 > 18368 [ACK] Seq=45212 Ack=46828 Len=0            
                                                           (The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.208397000 seconds)

   665 9.5068  ldapclient  ldapserver  LDAP    183 searchRequest(136)                                          
   666 9.5229  ldapserver  ldapclient  LDAP    163 searchResEntry(136)                                             
   667 9.5229  ldapserver  ldapclient  LDAP    170 searchResDone(136)
   ```

thanks,

Michael